# Making tabs automatically rotate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am not very proficient in JS and would like to help me with an issue I have. 
I want to make the tabs on a Drupal website automatically rotate but still the user to be able to click on them. 
This is the code I have:

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">        
        $('ul.checklist-select li').click(function () {
        var selectID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('ul.checklist-select li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.first-box, .second-box, .third-box, .fourth-box').fadeOut(300);
        $('.' + selectID + '-box').delay(300).fadeIn(300);});
        </script>
```

I tried few options but it wasn't working.Thanks very much! I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: No, I want the images to rotate alognside with the tabs. They way they do it on click, but to be automatically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want to add an interval that updates the view and rotates to the next one (or first if it's the last).

Try this (not tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var index = 0, // Index of current tab
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000), // Interval
    $tabs = $('ul.checklist-select'),
    $content = $('.checklist_wrap');

// Click handler
$('ul.checklist-select li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        index = i;
        switchElement();
    });
});

function rotate() {
    // Update index to next one
    index++;

    // Check if this is a valid index, or reset to 0
    if (index >= $tabs.children('li').length)
        index = 0;

    switchElement();
}

function switchElement() {
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Remove class from current tab
    $('ul.checklist-select li').removeClass('active');
    $('.checklist_wrap .box').fadeOut(300);

    // Show
    $tabs.children('li').eq(index).addClass('active');
    $content.children('.box').eq(index).delay(300).fadeIn(300);

    // Reset interval
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

<strike>Something you might want to add is that the interval is reset when someone clicks a tab.</strike>

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for that. Just tried but it is not working. It starts to rotate but the whole tabs+images section disappears.Same happens if you click on any of the tabs.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I only quickly glanced at your website's source code, so some of the selectors might not be right. I've just updated it, could you try it again?

Comment: Hi, well a bit better now. Now, it just starts to rotate but the images disappear and the tabs menu goes to the left, without active or hover stater. Weird. Tried to update the selectors but it is just the same. Thanks very much for helping me with that one.

Comment: Hi, yes, there were two errors. I've updated the code. You can also look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B6wxw/1/. I've also included an interval reset.

Comment: Hi!! It works just perfectly fine! I appreciate so much you help!!! Amazing jobs. Thanks very much! You saved my head today:))) I will put it online later today and you will see it.